# Is it possible for one entity to take data from two tables?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Is it possible to have one entity who takes data from two tables?

For example.

`Table1` has columns: `Id, Name, Table2_Id`

`Table2` has columns: `Id, FullName`

I have entity with properties: `Id, Name, FullName`

What I expect is configure (fluently) entity framework to build query:

```
select t1.Id, t1.Name, t2.FullName
from Table1 t1 join Table2 t2 on t1.Table2_id = t2.Id
```

Is it possible without has two separated entities and another one who merge both?

After quick google I find how to merge data from to tables into one entity. I need configure entity framework like this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
.Map( m => {
 m.Properties(x=> new { x.Id, x.Name });
 m.ToTable("Table1");
})
.Map( m => {
 m.Property(x=>x.FullName);
 m.ToTable("Table2");
});
```

But how to tell entity framework to join tables on `Table2_Id` from `Table1` and `Id` from `Table2`.

I know I can create view and map entity to view, but if possible I'd like to use the scenario I presented.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible or not but it should definitely not be, it's bad design. Merge two different entities if you like.

Comment: @Andreas - there are plenty of reasons to have an entity use two tables, for instance when you have a 1:1 table representation or a 1:0..1.  For example, best practice for BLOB's is to place them in their own table, but you might want them in your entity.  In addition, TPC inheritance is modeled with separate tables.

Comment: Then you would merge two different entities into a single, by the name of EntityAEntityB. This naming convention tells others what is going on.

Comment: @Andreas - No, you don't need naming conventions.  Your entity handles everything, and your mappings take care of the details if you need to know them.  Entity Framework is founded upon the principle that Entities do not have to match the table structure, so your insistence that this is bad is silly and goes against the very ideals of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if ID is the same in both tables, then you can make the 1:1 mapping map to a single entity.

You can also do Table Per Concrete Type inheritance, in which the inherited properties go in one table, and the derived properties go in another.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but first you must to create a view in the Database.

Like this:

>

```
create view my_view
as
select t1.Id, t1.Name, t2.FullName
from Table1 t1 join Table2 t2 on t1.Table2_id = t2.Id
```

2. You must to create a model in the project

like this:

>

```
public class my_view_model
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public string FullName{ get; set; }
}
```

3. Add the model in context (DbContext)

>

```
public virtual DbSet<my_view_model> my_view_model{ get; set; }
```

4. On Context, on OnModelCreating, add this:

>

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{           
    modelBuilder
       .Entity<my_view_model>(e =>
        {
             e.HasNoKey();
             e.ToView("my_view");
             e.Property(v => v.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
             e.Property(v => v.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
             e.Property(v => v.FullName).HasColumnName("FullName");
        });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```